# How to make Android Studio use one of the build-tools already installed in your machine?

Tags: android, android-studio

Usually when I import an Android Studio project from github there's an issue with the build-tools because I don't have installed *exactly* the same version used in the project. Is there a way to make Android Studio use one of the versions I have installed already instead of making me download the one in the project (which isn't necessarily more up to date than the ones I already have)? Case in point just the other day a project was making me download build-tools 23.0.1 which is ridiculous because I have 23.0.2, 23.0.3 and 24.0.0. If nothing else it could easily use 23.0.2, which it did after I manually changed the build.graddle to use one of my versions before finally being able to open the project in AS.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the build-tools version from build.gradle of the app module, by setting the value of the buildToolsVersion.

Comment: When you don't have the exact build-tools version the project is using AS doesn't even open the project so you can access the app module settings. That's why I have to change the build.gradle manually.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a way for AS to automatically upgrade the build tools version as you import any new project without resorting to changing it manually in the `build.gradle` file. From the perspective of a build tool this isn't really intuitive because if auto-upgrade strategy is adopted for such a scenario by the IDE then you may never know what features/functionalities were added/removed from the newer version. They may end up even breaking your project in ways that might get difficult to diagnose. Similar argument might be given for an auto-degrade strategy in these scenarios.

Note that, gradle does perform something similar to what you are asking during build time. While resolving module dependencies it automatically upgrades the version of any dependent module to the latest referenced one within that module. Eg:

```
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2
     +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.2 -> 1.3.3
     |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.7
     +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.6 -> 1.3.7
```

Here, gradle is assured that it didn't 'guessed' incorrectly because the modules were promoted to one referenced by you only.

However, the tools teams is always open for new feature requests [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Tools%20feature%20request).

Comment: I understand that there would be risks and it's something that everyone should be aware of before auto[upgrading|degrading] the build-tools used by the project in question however I'm still interested in knowing if there is a way to do this given that I accept those risks and I would keep them in mind. Usually there's nothing too edgy being used in those projects that would require you to have the exact build-tools version installed.

Comment: As of now, I don't think it is. You are welcome to do a feature request here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Tools%20feature%20request

Comment: Can you update your answer to include that comment? If no one has anything else yours would be the answer fwiw.